# Load data that is saved via AppStorage in Swift & SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, userdefaults, appstorage

I'm trying to save data (string) in SwiftUI via using @AppStrorage attribute, this works so far, but I would also like to be able to access and load the previously saved data in another place in my app.

I'm saving the data with this code:

```
@AppStorage("username") var username: String = "Anonymous"
```

Then, I'd like to get/fetch the saved "username" (in this case it should be "Anonymous") elsewhere in the code

If someone can help me, I would be very happy.

Thanks

Comment: Which classes? Do you really mean *classes* or SwiftUI view structs? Terminology is important.

Comment: I mean structures in other files

Answer (score 2):

`AppStorage` uses `UserDefaults` behind the scenes. So you should be able to access the data directly in a non-SwiftUI context that way.

For instance, if you are using App Storage to store a `Bool` if the user has performed some activity, these two should be identical.

```
struct YourView: View {
  @AppStorage("UserHasOnboarded") var hasOnboarded: Bool
  
  // View stuff
}

class SomeClass {
  func checkOnboarding() {
    let hasOnboarded = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "UserHasOnboarded")
    // Do your stuff
  }
}
```

When you use the `@AppStorage` wrapper, you can pass in the `UserDefaults` store to use. So if you're wanting to use one shared among an app group, for instance, you can pass that in when you create the wrapper, and then use that same group instance in your class, and you'd be able to access data in your app as well as your app extensions.

Comment: Thanks, but when I call up the string in a text via UserDefaults and unwrappe, the app crashes.

Comment: @LeoSaischowa `.string(forKey:)` returns an optional `String` type. If it's crashing, it means nothing is stored there yet. You should rarely force unwrap an optional and, instead, consider using guard-let or if-let patterns to safely handle these cases.

Comment: So, can I just write: if NAME != nil {
//   ... Code 
}

Comment: You can. Or `if let name = name { // 'name' is not optional here }`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use wrapper with same key, it is just reference to same `UserDefaults` storage

```
struct OneFileView: View {
  @AppStorage("someKey") var someKey: String
  
  // ... other code
}

struct AnotherFileView: View {
  @AppStorage("someKey") var someKey: String
  
  // ... other code
}
```